# airflow web url unable to connect

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am using celery executor with rabbitmq. Changed the airflow config file as below

```
broker_url = amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//
celery_result_backend = amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//
```

started the webserver & other services but webui url not working.
while list the dag getting below warning.

```
WARNING - You have configured a result_backend of amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//, it is highly recommended to use an alternative result_backend (i.e. a database).
Kindly help
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue originally too, then I ran pip install celery (after using a downgraded version per the article I was following).  With the newest version of celery now, the UI loaded and all appears working well.  But, I do still get those same warning messages for rabbitmq setup using amqp.  I assume it is because it is not officially supported.  See: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/2830/files